# Is propagation speed depending of wavelength? (QM)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, velocity, dispersion, phase-velocity

In case of a single free particle, no potential field, the wave function is:

$$ \Psi = A e^{i(kx-\omega t)}. $$

As it must fulfill the Schrödinger equation

$$ - \frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \nabla^2 \ \psi(\mathbf{r}, t) = i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \psi (\mathbf{r}, t) $$

it follows the restriction:

$$ \frac{\hbar^2 k^2}{2m} =\hbar \omega. $$

With this restriction the propagation speed $v$ became:

$$ v = \frac{w}{k} = \frac{h}{2m\lambda} $$

that depends in wavelength, being longer wavelengths slower.

Is this a real conclusion or I made some error in the derivation? Until now, always I've see propagation speed as a property of the medium only.

Answer (score 3):

There's no meaning to the speed $\omega/k$ for the Schroedinger equation, as you can add a constant potential without changing anything physical. What matters in the *group velocity*
$$
v_{\rm group} =\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial k}= \frac{\hbar k}{m} = \frac{p}{m}
$$
This is the speed at which a wavepacket travels, is independendent of any added constant potential, and as the classical momentum is $p=mv$, it is the speed at which the classical particle would move.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How these equations relates to the refractive index ?

Comment: The group velocity concept also applies to dispersive optical systems. Indeed that, and water waves, is where it came from long before Schroedinger.